# Error when fetching an OpenAI location URL

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch, openai-api

I tried a GET request for an SQL result from OpenAI SQL query API, but when I clicked I have the error and in console this error appear from image, please any can help me to fix that.

[image: this is my problem when iwant to get query]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)  (Or any of the many, many other questions found when searching the exact error message...)

Comment: What does your `fetch` call look like? Please include that in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I found your same [issue](https://community.openai.com/t/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/28905) on openAI community.

OpenAI has CORS blocked for security reason.
You shouldn't call openAI Api from your client, you are exposing your api key. Anyone can see your website code and steal your key.

You could use a proxy server or reverse proxy like [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) to forward the request adding Access-Contro-Allow-Origin: * (or your website domain).

(This is just a bypass but it doesn't fix the security issue)

A better solution is to create a backend service (with node if you are familiar with js/ts), which can handle user authentication and mask your openAI api calls.